# Radio button not checked when again loading form with ajax

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

I have an element which I use for upadting values in the database.

```
<p id="valuta">
  <label for="valuta">Valuta:</label><br/>
  <select id="valuta2" name="valuta2">
    <option value="USD">US </option>
    <option value="EUR">EUR </option>
    <option value="RSD">RSD </option>
  </select></br>
  Konvertuj cenu?</br>
  <input type="radio" id='conversion' class='conversion' name="conversion" checked="checked" value="1">DA<br>
  <input type="radio" class="conversion" name="conversion" value="2">NE
</p></br>
```

But when I try to load this element my radio button isnt checked. I am doing operation with ajax.

This is what I try after ajax operation in the success part:

```
 $('#conversion').prop('checked');
 $('#conversion').attr('checked');
 $('#conversion').attr('checked','checked')
```

no result? Any idea?

Comment: `$('#conversion').prop('checked', true);`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `.prop('checked', ...)` can be either `true` or `false`, so the correct code is:

```
$('#conversion').prop('checked', true);
```